# uninitialized property in prepareForSegue

Tags: objective-c, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm having some difficulty managing a segue. My view controller hierarchy is as follows:

- BHGSplitViewController (subclass of UISplitViewController)

  - UINavigationController

    - MasterViewController (subclass of UITableViewController)
  - UINavigationController

    - DetailViewController (subclass of UIViewController)

These have the following properties:

BHGSplitViewController:

```
@interface BHGSplitViewController : UISplitViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) MasterViewController* masterVC;

@end
```

MasterViewController:

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) MenuDataSource *menuDataSource;
@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;

@end
```

DetailViewController:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL* URL;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

These are related in my main storyboard through relationship segues.

After the initial app launch, I modally display a login view controller. After login, I segue back to my `BHGSplitViewController`, but I need to set some data. In the `loginViewController`'s `prepareForSegue` method I attempt the following:

```
BHGSplitViewController *splitVC = [segue destinationViewController];
splitVC.masterVC.menuDataSource.var = someValue;
```

But, when debugging, `splitVC.masterVC = nil`, so obviously attempting to set a value on it is not going to work. How do I set-up and retain those relationships?

I inherited a version of this app that was built with storyboards. I'm guessing that I need to start intializing these properties. What's the best way to do that with storyboards? Do I need to override `initWithCoder:`? Should I be setting these properties in `viewDidLoad`?

Edit: Explanation of segue

So, I'm loading up my `BHGSplitViewController` in my `AppDelegate` and setting it up to handle collapses, etc. After that, I need to immediately display a modal view for login. I need this to animate in like a push (but Apple won't allow that), so I'm trying to hack my way around that by using a custom segue (which is hacky and I hate it):

Present Segue:

```
- (void)perform {

    UIViewController *srcViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destViewController = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    UIView *prevView = srcViewController.view;
    UIView *destView = destViewController.view;

    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];

    [window insertSubview:destView aboveSubview:prevView];

    [destView enterLeft:0.1 then:^{
        [srcViewController presentViewController:destViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];

}
```

Dismiss Segue:

```
- (void)perform {

    UIViewController *srcViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    UIView *prevView = srcViewController.view;

    UIView *destView = destViewController.view;


    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];

    [window insertSubview:destView aboveSubview:prevView];

    [destView enterRight:0.1 then:^{
        [srcViewController presentViewController:destViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the properties in viewDidLoad. initWithCoder is definitely too early since the split view controller is instantiated first, and then the other controllers it houses. So, you can do this in viewDidLoad of BHGSplitViewController,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.viewControllers.firstObject;
    self.masterVC = (MasterViewController *)nav.topViewController;
}
```

Comment: trying this... `self.viewcontrollers` has two `UINavigationController`s but both are empty

Comment: @oflannabhra, how do you know they're empty? Does a log of nav.topViewController give you nil?

Comment: Sorry, not empty in the `viewDidLoad` method where I assign them, they are empty in the `prepareForSegue` where I try to set them. I am going from a modal view back to the splitView. I think the `prepareForSegue` is executing, then the splitView's `viewDidLoad` method is executing. Updating the question for clarity

Comment: @oflannabhra, that shouldn't be happening. viewDdiLoad is only called once during the lifetime of a controller. If viewDidLoad is being called again, then you're doing something wrong. What kind of segue are you using?

Comment: Updated original question with more info

Comment: @oflannabhra, ok, that's not the way to go back to another controller -- segues (other than unwinds) ALWAYS instantiate new controllers! So, you're creating a new split view controller, not going back to the original one. If you need the push style animation, then you need to write your own custom modal presentation and dismissal code using the new UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol, rather than using a segue.